# How to keyframe custom properties in actions?

Tags: animation, keyframes, actions, custom-properties

I'm using Blender to develop game animations. I have an animation that I want to attach hit boxes too. I then want to set boolean on/off values on keyframes the hit boxes are active and read this in game at run time.

Heres an example punch animation with hitbox attached to the hand bone.

[image]

On the last keyframe I'd like to set the hitbox to active. I thought I could use 'custom properties' for this. e.g. give the box a custom property of 'active' and then set it to 1.

I am using 'actions' to manage many separate animations. However it seems custom properties are not compatible with actions?

I'm confused because because the UI for the inserting key frames explicitly has a "Location, Rotation, Scale & Custom Poperties" option.

[image]

It appears that there is also a "custom properties" panel within the action editor :

[image]

This panel doesn't seem to respect the action time line and is always fixed to a value.

I've also tried adding the property to the armature itself

[image]

This doesn't get captured by the "Location, Rotation, Scale & Custom Poperties" option." insert.

I'm really just wondering exactly what custom properties the "Location, Rotation, Scale & Custom Poperties" insert option captures...

Comment: Don't know whether [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcTqlifue_g) YT tutorial will help?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to create a custom property to animate the activation of a hitbox. Wouldn't that be handled in the game engine anyway?

Comment: @L0Lock I want to use blender as the source of truth the game engine doesn't have an editor. I don't want to manually code up hitbox and frame data.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK right now, actions contain only keyframes from pose bones. So if you want to store custom properties' animation in an action, you need to create that custom property on a bone of the same armature.

For example, go in pose mode, select your hand bone, and got in Properties Editor > Bone Data tab > Custom Properties and create yours here:

[image]

This way, any animation on that custom property will be stored in the same action alongside the bones' other properties.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hover mouse cursor over the value slider and press <kbd>I</kbd>. It will create a keyframe

[image]

Comment: This method binds the key frames to a global time line and not the individual actions. This means if I set this key frame in one action it will also be unexpectedly set in the other actions.